# NSFileManager: Copy file not success

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, nsfilemanager

I want to copy files located at `/Library` to the folder `/User/Library/AddressBook/Sample/`,
I used:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath: @"/Library/MyFile.mp3" 
                                        toPath: @"/User/Library/AddressBook/Sample/MyFile.mp3" 
                                         error: &error];
```

But I encountered an error that says `Operation could not be completed. No such file or

directory`

**I am working on a jailbroken iPhone.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directory:

```
/User/Library/AddressBook/Sample/
```

does not exist on a phone normally.  Have you added the `Sample` subdirectory, before trying to copy the mp3 file into it?

With the `NSFileManager` methods, I would also recommend using the error object to help you debug:

```
NSError* error;
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:@"/Library//MyFile.mp3" toPath: @"/User/Library/AddressBook/Sample/MyFile.mp3" error:&error];

if (error != nil) {
    NSLog(@"Error message is %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Also, it looks like there is a mistake in your spelling of `copyItemAtPath`, but probably it's only in your **question**, and not in your **code**?  Anyway, please double-check.

And, you have a double-slash (`//`) in your path, too, but I don't think that's hurting you.  Just take it out, and be careful when typing :)

### Update

If you are just running this app *normally*, but on a jailbroken phone, your app won't have access to those directories.  Apps installed normally, on a jailbroken phone, still are *sandboxed*.  The jailbreak doesn't remove all the rules on the phone.  If you install the app in `/Applications`, like true jailbreak apps are, then that code should work for you.

Comment: I added 'Sample' subdirectory before copy the mp3 file into it. </br>
Sorry for typo. Now I used: </br>
NSError* error;
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:@"/Library/MyFile.mp3" toPath: @"/User/Library/AddressBook/Sample/MyFile.mp3" error:&error];

if (error != nil) {
    NSLog(@"Error message is %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

Comment: @user1561904 Ok, so are you still seeing an error?  What does `"Error message is ..."` show you?

Comment: Operation Could not be completed. No such file or directory

Comment: @user1561904, How are you running your app?  Are you just using the normal iOS process, where you code sign the app with your developer provisioning profile, then Build and Run from Xcode?  Or, are you installing the app in /Applications/ via some other process?

Comment: @user1561904, Please run the commands `ls -al /User/Library/AddressBook/` and `ls -al /Library/` at the iPhone's command line, and show us the result.  Please use the **edit** link above, to add it to your question, and not down here as a *comment*.  It will be more readable up above.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *libraryDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"%@",libraryDirectory); // Library path
NSString *AddressBookPath = [libraryDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"AddressBook"];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:AddressBookPath])
{        
    NSError* error;
    // Create "AddressBook Dir"
    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:AddressBookPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error])
    {
        // Create "Sample Dir"
        NSString *samplePath = [AddressBookPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Sample"];
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:AddressBookPath])
        {                
            NSError* error;
            if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:AddressBookPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error])
            {
                // Copy Files Now
                NSError* error;
                NSString *fromPath = [libraryDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyFile.mp3"];
                NSString *toPath = [samplePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyFile.mp3"];
                [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:fromPath toPath:toPath error:&error];

                if (error != nil)
                {
                    NSLog(@"Error message is %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"[%@] ERROR: attempting to write create MyFolder directory", [self class]);
        NSAssert( FALSE, @"Failed to create directory maybe out of disk space?");
    }
}
```